# Is it normal for java library code to throw & catch lots of exceptions during "normal" processing?

Tags: java

More as an experiment, I decided to enable the following breakpoint in the Eclipse debugger: `Throwable [Include Subclasses]: caught and uncaught`.  I then let my code (which is running "fine" as far as I know) run under the debugger, and was surprised to see dozens of exceptions being thrown and caught (previously unknown to me) by standard J2SE library code when my code was running normally for all I know.

For example, here are just some of the Java framework functions I found throwing exceptions: `URLClassLoader.findClass`, `FileDirContext.lookup`, and `WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal`.

Is this considered normal behavior for a Java application?  Is this something I should look into?  My code seems to be running fine as far as I know.

Comment: These all sound reasonable: the exceptions happen when a primary (or *n*-ary in general) retrieval mechanism fails and is probably handled by trying a secondary (or (*n+1*)-ary in general) mechanism.

Comment: You should follow the specification (documentation) on the methods rather than worrying about what they might be doing internally. That type of research is only necessary if the implemenation doesn't behave as expected according to the specification.

Comment: That's a very good question, and I guess that the answer depends on the specific exceptions that are being thrown. In general, as a thumb rule, it is a bad practice to design your code to rely on catching exceptions because exceptions are expensive. A good read: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05254/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exceptions thrown during class-loading are relic from early days in Java history when class loading was designed to use them as a way how to communicate that some class-loader was not able to find a class. It is not considered to be a good pattern now but it remains there and probably won't be changed ever as it is part of APIs. Nothing to be scared of.

Answer (score 2):

Though it is bad to design your code in this way (exceptions are slow, and should be used for exceptional circumstances), Bhesh Gurung's comment is the right way to think about this.  Follow the specification of the code you are relying on, and don't worry about the implementation.

Comment: Arguably, it **is an exceptional circumstance** when the loading of a requested resource fails. This is exactly the definition of the use case of checked exceptions: **expected**, but **exceptional** circumstances.